# How do I delete my public cocoa pods

Tags: cocoapods

I have created a couple test cocoa pods that are public I need to delete these not just from my computer but from the public pod list? Is there a way to remove the trunk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete these specs entirely you'll need to submit a pull request to the [specs repo](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs) removing the affected files. If you want to also remove them from the trunk database, you'll have to submit an issue on the [trunk repo](https://github.com/CocoaPods/trunk.cocoapods.org) explaining the situation.

Answer (score 7):

In order to complete the **@Keith Smiley's response**, please find some other important details below:

**Can I submit a pull request if...**

**Q: I want to update my Pod to a new version?**

A: No, this is no longer the appropriate way to update your Pod. Pod updates must be uploaded using pod trunk push [NAME.podspec].

**Q: I made a mistake in a Podspec I've just pushed?**

A: No. The quickest way to get this fixed is to edit your .podspec, bump the version number and pod trunk push [NAME.podspec].

**Q: I've deleted this Pod?**

A: People are relying on your library, you should apply [the deprecated flag](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#deprecated) via a [pull request](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs) to all versions of your library. Removal of Podspecs should be avoided as much as possible. This is to ensure systems built around the CocoaPods ecosystem are kept in sync.

**Q: No one needs that pod, or is going to ever download it... why can't I just delete it?**

A: Our policy is to only perma-delete pods that really need it, such as Pods that may contain passwords, malicious/harmful code, etc. Deprecating a pod effectively removes it from being found and will do the trick in 99% percent of situations.

**Q: But what if..**

A: Chances are, no.

(**Sources** of this answer: [link 1](https://github.com/CocoaPods/trunk.cocoapods.org/issues/139), [link 2](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/pull/12199))

Comment: What is the best way to add the deprecated flag if the specs repository is no longer accepting PRs, since they have moved to trunk. Is it even possible to deprecate now?

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea, you should ask that question to @ Keith Smiley above, commenting his answer. I think he could know the answer to your question.

Comment: @King-Wizard, Will deprecating a pod will allow any other person to publish a pod with that same name? If not, what's the procedure to completely remove pod so that any other person can publish pod with same name?